# deploy azure function from visual studio via proxy

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I am trying to deploy an Azure function project from Visual Studio 2017 to Azure but I am getting a proxy authentication error.

I have added the local proxy settings to Visual Studio config but still cannot get it to work.

```
 <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress=" HYPERLINK "http://<yourproxy:port#>" 
     http://<yourproxy:port#>"/>
 </defaultProxy>
```

Is there anyway I can set the proxy in the JSON configuration similar to how it can be done in web application config to get around this problem?

I appreciate your help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. If anyone has the  same problem this may work for you

1. Add proxy settings for msdeploy.exe, you need to find it first (usually in C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3) and edit msdeploy.exe.config file

   ```
   <system.net>
   <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
   </system.net>
   ```
2. In the publishing profile of your project (you can have multiple) which is located under your project > Properties > PublishProfiles, you need to add the following line so that it uses msdeploy.exe for publishing.

   ```
   <UseMsdeployExe>true</UseMsdeployExe>
   ```